# Mongoose switching multiple connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Node.Js 8.6 along with Mongoose 4.11 and have multiple database connections. Db connections are established via `mongoose.createConnection`.
I found out that `mongoose` object has `connections` property (array), where I can see established connections. My question is, what is the proper way, to switch between connections when creating db models in separate modules.

index.js

```
async function db1() {
    await mongoose.createConnection(
        process.env.MONGODB_URI_1,
        { useMongoClient: true }
    );
}

async function db2() {
    await mongoose.createConnection(
        process.env.MONGODB_URI_2,
        { useMongoClient: true }
    );
}
```

model.js

```
//connect to db1

const Test1 = mongoose.model('Test1', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));

//connect to db2

const Test2 = mongoose.model('Test2', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object return by `createConnection` in order to handle your multiple connections.

```
const db1Link = await mongoose.createConnection(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI_1,
    { useMongoClient: true }
);

// Connect to db1
db1Link.model('Test1', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));

const db2Link = await mongoose.createConnection(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI_2,
    { useMongoClient: true }
);

// Connect to db2
db2Link.model('Test2', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));
```

---

[Here is what the documentation says about it](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

> Multiple connections
>
> So far we've seen how to connect to MongoDB using Mongoose's default
>   connection. At times we may need multiple connections open to Mongo,
>   each with different read/write settings, or maybe just to different
>   databases for example. In these cases we can utilize
>   mongoose.createConnection() which accepts all the arguments already
>   discussed and returns a fresh connection for you.
>
> ```
> var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]', options);
> ```
>
> This connection object is then used to create and retrieve models.
>   Models are always scoped to a single connection.

Comment: That's true. What would be the elegant way to share those connection objects around the modules?

Answer (score 1):

//config.json

```
   {
    "Tenants": {
            "5c061f432c9e9e499325b": {
                "dbConfig": "mongodb://admin:Password@IP/DBname",
                "dbName": "DBname",

            },
            "5c0432ebabb6c9e9e499325b": {
                "dbConfig": "mongodb://admin:Password@IP/DBname",
                "dbName": "DBname",

            },
            "5c061f43bb6c9e9e499325b": {
                "dbConfig": "mongodb://admin:Password@IP/DBname",
                "dbName": "DBname",

            }
        },

    }
```

//ModelFactory.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var models = [];
var conns = [];
var path = __dirname + "\\models";
var config = require("config");


function factory(tenant) {
    let dbName = config.get("Tenants." + tenant + ".dbName");
    let dbConnection = config.ge`enter code here`t("Tenants." + tenant + ".dbConfig");
    if (conns[dbName]) {
    } else {
        conns[dbName] = mongoose.createConnection(dbConnection);
    }
    if (models[dbName]) {
    } else {
        var instanceModels = [];
        var schemas = ["users","products"];
        schemas.forEach(function (models) {
            instanceModels[models] = conns[dbName].model(models, require([path, models].join("\\")));
        });
        // DB name and tenant ID also pushing in the same object
        //instanceModels["tenantID"] = tenant; 
        //instanceModels["db"] = conns[dbName];
        models[dbName] = instanceModels;        
    }
    return models[dbName];
}
module.exports = factory;
```

//API End point

```
exports.users = function (req, res) {

var models = modelFactory(req.headers.tenantid);
models.User.find() //query
```